# Test class returning unexpected data

Tags: apex

In a testclass,

if i write below as my first line of code

```
integer c= [select count() from user];
```

why does it return total count of user.
although i have not created any test data in my class.
Is this something with User object?

Comment: can you please post test class in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are visible in a Test context regardless of seeAllData.

For instance, in a typical test factory class, this is how we get our Admin User:

```
public static User ADMIN_USER
{
    get
    {
        if (ADMIN_USER == null)
            {
                ADMIN_USER = [SELECT  Id FROM User WHERE  Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
        }
        return ADMIN_USER;
    }
    set {}
}
```

If you want only users you have created, it should look something like the following:

```
final Integer NUM_OF_USERS = Limits.getLimitQueries();
List<User> testUsers = testFactory.createUsers(NUM_OF_USERS);
Integer numUsers = [SELECT count() FROM User WHERE Id IN :testUsers];
system.assertEquals(NUM_OF_USERS, numUsers, 'All users should be created.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your whole test class but I assume your test class can see all data.

In your code you haven't specified anything to limit what is being returned by the query. It is simply returning the results of your SOQL query. Perhaps if you are creating a user in your test class, you can query as:

```
integer c= [select count() from user WHERE Username='createdUser'];
```

This way you end up fetching what you created in your test class.